# How to print a required number

Tags: python

Per the image below, I got an error while displaying the number in the second program i.e. `nbrs=list(range(1,11))` at the start of the second program... so I want to know the reason of the error in the second program, which I didn't get in the first program.

[image]

Comment: You already have a valid answer, but for future questions, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code as well-formatted text, and not as a picture. If people want to run your code to recreate your error, they want to be able to cut-and-paste into into their IDE, not to have to type it in from a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple type error, because you want to append a `str` with an `int`. `+` is an operand to attach two `str` or to add two `int`. Please take a look at [this](https://pythonprinciples.com/blog/converting-integer-to-string-in-python/). It is better to use something like `format` to output different types:

```
print("{} <--is multiples of".format(n))
```

`format` keep care of different types, convert them to a `str` and append them at the desired position. See [here](https://pyformat.info/) for more information.